# flexbox dropdown menu items wont flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, emotion

I have a Navbar when a link is hovered a 100% width dropdown menu appears. The dropdown is a flex item, but the links in the menu dont react to justify-content.

HTML set up using Next.js Links and emotion/styled:

```
<NavContainer className="navContainer">
            <Nav className="nav">
                <Dropdown className="dropdown">
                    <Link href="/about"><AnchorMain>About Us</AnchorMain></Link>
                    <DropdownContent className="dropdown-content">
                        <Link href="/about/#"><a>COVID-19 Resources</a></Link>
                        <Link href="/about/#"><a>Mission</a></Link>
                        <Link href="/about/#"><a>FAQ</a></Link>
                    </DropdownContent>
                </Dropdown>
             </Nav>
</NavContainer>
```

And here is my css using emotion/styled:

```
const Dropdown = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    &:hover {
        .dropdown-content {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
`;

const DropdownContent = styled.div`
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 0 1000em;
    margin: 0 -1000em;
    background-color: #056cfebd;
    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 250px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: flex-start;

    a {
        color: #FEA620;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 150px;
        left: 0;
    }
`;
```

Comment: width:100% maybe ?

Comment: If I add width:100% to DropdownContent only if I use justify-content:space-evenly do the items move. But even then, if I flex-wrap:wrap, all the items go into a single column.